# C++ Decrypt chrome cookies

Tags: hash, cookies, google-chrome, encryption, c++

I need to read Chrome cookies in C++, but Chrome encrypts them all. All the other methods of decrypting the cookies I have found are now no longer working, anyone know the latest way to do this?

Comment: Which OS? The cookies are encrypted a different way for different OSes.

Comment: @nobody windows 10

Answer (score 3):

Please see for information how Chrome 80+ protects cookies: https://xenarmor.com/how-to-recover-saved-passwords-google-chrome/

> New Chrome version (v80.0 & higher) uses Master Key based encryption to store your web login passwords.

> Here is how it generates the Master Key. First 32-byte random data is generated. Then it is encrypted using Windows DPAPI (“CryptProtectData”) function. To this encrypted key, it inserts signature “DPAPI” in the beginning for identification.

> Finally this key is encoded using Base64 and stored in “Local State” file in above “User Data” folder.

Or here: [Did changes in Google Chrome 80 weaken cookie and password encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/230137/did-changes-in-google-chrome-80-weaken-cookie-and-password-encryption)